# Does Windows 10 version 1903 come with Chrome

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, windows-installation

I just installed Windows 10 version 1903. After the installation completed, I found Google Chrome was installed. However, I don't want Chrome on this Windows 10 machine.

**Question:** Does Chrome come with Windows 10 version 1903?

- My guess is that it does not but looking for 100% for certain confirmation.

[image]

Comment: "Does it come with Windows 10?" - Chrome is absolutely no installed by default;  There is something else, that has not been identified, that explains the reason Chrome was installed.  Is this computer connected an Active Directory domain?

Comment: Did you just upgrade to 1903 from a previous version of Windows 10?

Comment: @music2myear: This is a clean installation of Windows 10 built 1903. Everything on C:\ was wiped off. I actually partition and format the drive first before installation.

Comment: @Ramhound: This computer is on a home LAN with internet connection.

Comment: It is extremely easy to install Chrome.  Are you absolutely positive you didn’t accidentally install it?  Are you sure it’s even installed?  Add a screenshot of Add/Remove Programs showing Chrome is installed

Comment: In Settings>Apps, there is Google Chrome with a date of 20/9/2019 (today). When I clicked on it, I got an option of "uninstall". There was a Chrome icon on desktop, which I quickly deleted. Yes, it's so easy to install Chrome by accident. Whenever I go to the Google's home page, it always asks me whether I want to switch to Chrome. I might have hit the install button by accident, although I do not remember doing it.

Comment: Are you going to add the information I requested to your question?

Comment: I don't know how to post picture. Never done it before.

Comment: Start by clicking the EDIT button under your question. Use Print Screen (or the Snipping tool) to capture an image of the required information, and upload it using the appropriate control in the post editor.

Comment: @music2myear Thanks for the tip. I have added a screen dump that shows Google Chrome in Apps.

Comment: Next thing is to list the applications you DID install, and check the Event Viewer for records regarding Chrome, or from around the time when Chrome was installed.

Comment: Ramhound answered your question, point blank period, "No it does not come with Windows 10". It is a separately installed package regardless of how it is getting installed. The "how" is **too broad** of a question but the actual **question sentence** in your question with the question "**`?`**" was answered in the first comment you received.

Comment: Where are you getting the Windows 10 version 1903 install media from. Maybe you need to download or use different media. The default [right from MS](https://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/software-download/windows10) does not contain Chrome in my recent experience of hundreds of installations of version 1903 in particular.

Comment: It dosen't. I do notice you installed partition master - could it have bundled chrome?

Comment: Chrome does not come bundled in _any_ [official image](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) of Windows.  However Internet Explorer should be manually uninstalled (via Add or Remove Features), due the critical exploit that was found in April which will not be patched (Microsoft has ceased development of Internet Explorer) and [Edge Beta](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download) should be installed if wanting to only utilize a Microsoft browser (the new Edge is chromium-based and far superior to the Edge browser bundled with Windows 10).

Comment: Ok. So, I must have installed Chrome by accident.